# Дублирующийся вывод комментария

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть код для вывода комментариев. Но при событии onClick с помощью метода addNewPost()  выводиться 2 дублирующих комментария вместо одного. По факту в state с помощью .push идет 2 объекта. Что я упустил здесь? Спасибо тем кто поможет.

```
import React from 'react'
import './postLog.css';
import './makeMessage.css';
import PostItem from './PostItem';




class PostLog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        };
        console.log(this.state.posts)
    }
    auto_grow = (event) => {
        event.target.style.height = "5px";
        event.target.style.height = (event.target.scrollHeight) + "px";
    }
    addNewPost = () => {
        let textArea = document.querySelector(".body-page__hero-posts-textarea-input")
        let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString().slice(0, -3)
        let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString()
        let userNik = this.props.name
        this.setState(function () {
            return this.state.posts.push(
                {
                    nikName: userNik,
                    dataDate: `${date}`,
                    dataTime: `${time}`,
                    textBody: textArea.value
                }
            )
        });
        console.log(this.state.posts)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="body-page__hero-posts-log">
                <div className="body-page__hero-posts">
                    <div className="body-page__hero-posts-title">Add message</div>
                    <div className="body-page__hero-posts-textarea">
                        <textarea onInput={this.auto_grow} className="body-page__hero-posts-textarea-input" type="text" placeholder="some news?.." />
                    </div>
                    <div className="body-page__hero-posts-submit">
                        <button onClick={this.addNewPost} type="submit" className="blue-btn" id="neon-text">Publish</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="body-page__hero-posts-logs-wrapper">
                    {
                        this.state.posts.map((item) => (item ? <PostItem key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)} nikName={item.nikName} dataDate={item.dataDate} dataTime={item.dataTime} textBody={item.textBody} /> : null))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default PostLog;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

```
this.setState({
            posts : [...this.state.posts, {
                    nikName: userNik,
                    dataDate: `${date}`,
                    dataTime: `${time}`,
                    textBody: textArea.value
                }]
        });
```

корень проблемы лежит в имутабельности объектов. Вы не изменяете сам `state`, а задаете новый клонированный из старого с добавлением нового элемента.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло.